# JAVA parse special characters

Tags: java, html

I have a program which collecting some HTML data.

```
public class Uni_Extract {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Started");

        String csvFile = "C://Users/Kennedy/Desktop/university.csv";
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(csvFile);

        for (int i=2; i<=2; i++){
            String url = "http://www.4icu.org/reviews/index"+i+".htm";
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla").get();

            Elements cells = doc.select("td.i");

            Iterator<Element> iterator = cells.iterator();  
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Element cell = iterator.next();

                String university = Jsoup.parse((cell.select("a").text())).text();
                university = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(university);
                String country = cell.nextElementSibling().select("img").attr("alt");
                System.out.printf("country : %s, university : %s %n", country, university);
            }
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

However, my program when come across some special charcters, it will return the original HTML code. How should I parse them?

For example, it will return Azerbaycan Dövlet Pedaqoji Universiteti containing "ö" as special char? How could I solve it and other similar cases?

Comment: Here's what's actually in the HTML: `Azerbaycan D&ouml;vlet Aqrar Universiteti`. I assume that's what your code outputs? And presumably you would like to see `ö` instead of `&ouml;`. If so, what you're looking for is a way to unescape HTML.

Comment: Oh, looking at your code, it looks like you're calling `escapeHtml` yourself. What happens if you stop doing that? (I think `Jsoup` unescaped it for you already, but you're re-escaping it for some reason.)

Comment: Your code also tries to use a variable `university1` that doesn't exist. Can you share an actual running example?

Comment: It is just a testing added before. Sorry for confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little simplification of your code and removing the call to `escapeHtml`, everything seems to work correctly. Here's my code and the relevant line of output:

```
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import org.jsoup.select.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Started");

        String url = "http://www.4icu.org/reviews/index2.htm";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla").get();

        Elements cells = doc.select("td.i");

        Iterator<Element> iterator = cells.iterator();  
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Element cell = iterator.next();

            String university = Jsoup.parse((cell.select("a").text())).text();
            String country = cell.nextElementSibling().select("img").attr("alt");
            System.out.printf("country : %s, university : %s %n", country, university);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
...
country : Azerbaijan, university : Azerbaycan Dövlet Aqrar Universiteti
...
```